# align divs vertically top and some on bottom

Tags: html, css

I have three `div` elements to arrange vertically as follows

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="nb">
                <div class="top"></div>
                <div class="top"></div>
                <div class="bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dynamic">Height will change dynamically</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here the height of `.dynamic` will change dynamically. So the height of the `td` will be changed.
I want to stick `.top` on top of `td`, and `.bottom` on bottom of `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ..

```css
.nb {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative
}
.top {
  float: top;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="nb">
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dynamic">Height will change dynamically</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is ok. but  the height (nb, top, bottom) will change dynamically depending what the content in it. So without specifying a fixed height, how can do it.

Comment: @ShihabuRahman just remove `height` and `width` in `.class` and `.bottom`

Comment: But when using multiple 'td' it needed  "vertical-align: top;" for each 'td'. Solved all issues. thanks