# vertically align some text top and other text bottom div

Tags: javascript, css

I split a div into left (translations) and right (links). Now I want three lines of text on the right to be aligned to the top and a forth line to be aligned to the bottom. So I created two `div`s (topLinks and bottomLinks). But I can't get the right `div` to be the same height as the left. And so the text in bottomLinks shows up right after the topLinks.

How do I get the `OPTIONS` link to be bottom-aligned?

(Also, I'm using `<p>` for indent, I think if I set the line-spacing to 0 and use `<br>` I can avoid the extra height after "aged". Is there a better alternative?)

[image: Bottom Align Fail]

.css

```
.links {
  float:right;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:right;
  font-size:11px;
}

.bottomlinks {
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

.js

```
function renderBubble() {
    var translations = document.createElement('div');
    translations.setAttribute('class', 'translations');

    var translationText = 'alt:<br><b>';
    var words = ['old', 'ancient', 'aged'];
    for (var index=0; index<Math.min(5, words.length); index++) {
        translationText += '<p class="tab">' + words[index] + '</p>';
    }
    translationText += '</b>';
    translations.innerHTML = translationText;

    var links = document.createElement('div');
    links.setAttribute('class', 'links');

    var topLinks = document.createElement('div');
    topLinks.setAttribute('class', 'toplinks');
    var linksText = '';
    linksText += '<a target="_blank" href="https://glosbe.com/...>';
    linksText += 'ADD or DETAIL glosbe.com&rarr;</a><br>';
    linksText += '<a target="_blank" href="https://translate.google.com/...>';
    linksText += 'TRANSLATE at google&rarr;</a><br>';
    linksText += '<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/...>';
    topLinks.innerHTML = linksText;

    var bottomLinks = document.createElement('div');
    bottomLinks.setAttribute('class', 'bottomlinks');
    var optionsText = '';
    optionsText += '<a target="_blank" href="https://options">';
    optionsText += 'OPTIONS&rarr;</a>';
    bottomLinks.innerHTML = optionsText;

    links.appendChild(topLinks);
    links.appendChild(bottomLinks);

    bubbleDOM.appendChild(translations);
    bubbleDOM.appendChild(links);

    // I tried the following to force the 'OPTIONS' text to be bottom aligned
    var maxHeight = Math.max(translations.offsetHeight, links.offsetHeight);
    translations.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
    links.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544615/align-divs-vertically-top-and-some-on-bottom